# How to play videos one by one in android from array of video links

Tags: android

For single video play in android I am using this code snippet Its working fine for me

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(<videoLink>), "video/*");
        startActivity(intent);
```

but I have Number videos in ArrayList and I want play those videos One by one

what neet to change in below code

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(<Parse arraylist of VideoLinks and play one by one > , "video/*");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -2):

Make an arraylist of ur URIs

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
imageUris.add(imageUri1); // Add your image URIs here
imageUris.add(imageUri2);
```

Then,

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
```

Comment: I am getting this error  04-18 13:39:01.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2663): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE (has extras) }

Comment: I think this answer is totally wrong because you're setting 2 actions for an Intent. One is to view and another to send so its ambiguous for the system to work like this.